# .Net Maui Shell Navigation - Is it possible to pass a Query Parameter and Auto Populate a Page?

Tags: xaml, .net-maui

I need to auto populate a Page by passing a Shell Navigation Parameter to a ViewModel/Method and call a Service to return a single record from a Web Service.  Essentially a drill-through page.  My issue is that I need to call the data retrieveal command, "GetFieldPerformanceAsync" (note [ICommand] converts this to "GetFieldPerformanceCommand") from the "To" Page's code-behind from within *OnNavigatedTo*.  This is required since the Shell Navigation Parameter is not set in the ViewModel until the Page is loaded.  I'm currently unable to make the Command call from *OnNavigatedTo* and need advice on how to accomplish this.

Thanks!

Code behind the Page:

```
public partial class FieldPerformancePage : ContentPage
{
   public FieldPerformancePage(FieldPerformanceViewModel viewModel)
   {
       InitializeComponent();
       BindingContext = viewModel;
    
       //works with parameter hard-coded in ViewModel
       //viewModel.GetFieldPerformanceCommand.Execute(null);
   }

   FieldPerformanceViewModel viewModel;
   protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigatedToEventArgs args)
   {
       base.OnNavigatedTo(args);
       //this does not work 
       viewModel.GetFieldPerformanceCommand.Execute(null);
   }
}
```

ViewModel

```
namespace TrackMate.ViewModels;

[QueryProperty(nameof(FieldAssignedWbs), nameof(FieldAssignedWbs))]
public partial class FieldPerformanceViewModel : BaseViewModel
{
   [ObservableProperty]
   FieldAssignedWbs fieldAssignedWbs;

   [ObservableProperty]
   FieldPerformance fieldPerformance;

   FieldPerformanceService fieldPerformanceService;

   public FieldPerformanceViewModel(FieldPerformanceService fieldStatusService)
   {
       Title = "Status";
       this.fieldPerformanceService = fieldStatusService;
   }

   [ICommand]
   async Task GetFieldPerformanceAsync()
   {
       if (IsBusy)
           return;
       try
       {
           IsBusy = true;

           int wbsId = fieldAssignedWbs.WbsId;

           var fieldPerformanceList = await fieldPerformanceService.GetFieldPerformanceList(wbsId);

           if (fieldPerformanceList.Count != 0)
               FieldPerformance = fieldPerformanceList.First();
       }
       catch (Exception ex)
       {
           Debug.WriteLine(ex);
           await Shell.Current.DisplayAlert("Error!",
               $"Undable to return records: {ex.Message}", "OK");
       }
       finally
       {
           IsBusy = false;
       }
   }
}
```

Comment: What's the `GetFieldPerformanceCommand` in your `viewModel`? How can we reproduce this problem? If it is convinient you,could you please post a basic demo so that we can try to test on our side?

Comment: Jessie, I may resolved my issue by adding ViewModel Binding in the "To" Page Code Behind.  In my test project you can see the Comand Call, in the DetailsPage Code Behind.  It calls the ViewModel which auto populates the "To" Page.  This is my first upload to GitHub so please let me know of any ommisions.  https://github.com/ToddTaylorPL/AutoPopulatePage.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe I figured it out...

By adding ViewModel Binding within the OnNavigatedTo method in the "DetailsPage" Code Behind, a Command Call can be made to the Page's ViewModel to execute data retrieval method after the Shell Navigation Parameter (object in this scenario) passed from the "Main" Page has been set.  Note a null is passed since the Query Parameter is sourced from the ViewModel.  If you are new to .Net Maui, as I am, I recommend James Montemagno's video on .Net Maui Shell Navigation.

```
namespace TrackMate.Views;

public partial class FieldPerformancePage : ContentPage
{
   public FieldPerformancePage(FieldPerformanceViewModel viewModel)
   {
      InitializeComponent();
      BindingContext = viewModel;
   }

   protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigatedToEventArgs args)
   {
       FieldPerformanceViewModel viewModel = (FieldPerformanceViewModel)BindingContext;
       viewModel.GetFieldPerformanceCommand.Execute(null);

       base.OnNavigatedTo(args);
   }
}
```

Comment: Congrats, and thanks for sharing answer here. :)

Comment: This is so old-school Xamain-like. Why don't you use the Maui dependency injection extension? If you register your ViewModel like `builder.Services.AddSingleton<FieldPerformanceViewModel >();` in `MauiMain.cs`?

Comment: you can also implement partial OnFieldAssignedWbsChanged, but since you use async/await won't work in your case, but still something to keep in mind. I've added it as a separate answer

Answer (score 0):

For me it only worked when the BindingContext assignment is before the component initialization and the method call after the base call in OnNavigatedTo

```
public partial class OccurrencePage : ContentPage
{

    public OccurrencePage(OccurrenceViewModel model)
    {
        BindingContext = model;
        InitializeComponent();
    }

  

    protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigatedToEventArgs args)
    {
        base.OnNavigatedTo(args);

        OccurrenceViewModel viewModel = (OccurrenceViewModel)BindingContext;
        viewModel.GetFieldsCommand.Execute(null);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

While overriding **OnNavigatedTo** works fine, there is one more simple technique to run something once your query param is set, given you do not need to run anything asynchronous inside the method: implementing partial method **OnFieldAssignedWbsChanged**, auto-generated for your convenience by mvvm toolkit

```
    partial void OnFieldAssignedWbsChanged(FieldAssignedWbs value)
    {
        // run synchronous post query param set actions here 
    }
```

Less amount of code and less code-behind and viewModel dependencies, but works fine for non-async operations only.